# Server Client sending an object

Tags: java, swing

I want to send a class back and forth between Client and Server. Want to run the Panel class from client. Please can anyone tell what can i do??

**Client Class**:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Client
{
    private static Socket socket = null;
    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, EOFException
    {
        try {
            socket = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host: localhost");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

When I want to read the panel object from client there will be an error that say main class not found. How can I access the panel class from client???

**server class**:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 4444.");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    Socket socketOut = serverSocket.accept();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socketOut.getOutputStream()) ;
    socketOut.close();
    serverSocket.close();
 }
}
```

**Panel class**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Panel extends JPanel {
    public Panel()
    {
        JTextField n = new JTextField(10);
        n.setText("Hello");
        JButton q = new JButton("Who are you?");
        setSize(300,300);
        add(n);
        add(q);
        setLayout (new FlowLayout());
   }
}
```

Comment: what exactly is the error message? I see only main method here, no main class... Did you copy all classes to moth client and server classpaths?

Comment: class problem solved but how can i use another jFrame,jpanel class from server client process

Answer (score 0):

To send an object between to distinct processes via sockets you need to serialize the object. So the Panel class needs to implement the Serializable interface: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/

As for the main class not found thing. I assume the two classes must be two separately processes. In which case you may find that if you are building this in an IDE that the main class definition is Server for both projects. You may need to correct this. Ensure that there are two separate build results with two separate main classes.

Comment: Thanks for your help. but i can manage to show the Jframe window by creating an object. but there are some action in the Jframe class. how can i run them???

Comment: Try serializing it, this deflates the whole object for transmission and rebuilds it at the other end. If you create an object you lose any changes you made.

Comment: ok done
i have two or more JFrame class work one after another. do i have to write all of their class name in client class??? i use setvisible for one class. the remaining classes comes after one another after this class. but the dont in server client. what can i do???

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand what you mean can you post example code.

Comment: i posted example code. here eagle eye is a normal jframe class. when i try to access it from the client a window will appear in server side. i want to play it from client side. what can i do??? @feldoh

Comment: It looks like you are setting it visible on creation. I believe that you need to call set visible at the destination after the transmission. If you need to control one system from another then either using sockets and sending messages or using Java RMI might be what you need: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html

Comment: Also is there any need to create the JFrame on the server. Usually I would expect it to be created client side to get a valid window handle and OS appropriate styling. I would suggest adding your image and mouse listener to a JPanel rather than a JFrame then when reading a JPanel object from the stream you create a new JFrame and add the panel using the .setContentPane(receivedJPanel) method. This would achieve the same thing.

Comment: Also sorry about the slow response, I was away for a day.

Answer (score 0):

**Server Class:**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

class ServerThread extends Thread {
    private Socket socket = null;

    public ServerThread(Socket socket) {
    super("ServerThread");
    this.socket = socket;
    }

    public void run() {

    try {
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()) ;
            EagleEye y = new EagleEye();
            Object object = y;
            oos.writeObject(object);
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
            socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}

public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        boolean listening = true;

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 4444.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        while (listening)
        new ServerThread(serverSocket.accept()).start();

        serverSocket.close();
    }
}
```

**Client Class:**

```
public class Client {
    private static Socket socket = null;
    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, EOFException{
    try {
            socket = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host: localhost");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        EagleEye y = (EagleEye)ois.readObject();
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

**EagleEye (normal Jframe class):**

```
public class EagleEye extends JFrame implements Serializable {
    private JLabel label1;
    private Icon photo;

    public EagleEye(){
        super("EAGLE EYE");
        photo= new ImageIcon( getClass().getResource( "Untitled.jpg" ) );
        label1= new JLabel();
        label1.setIcon(photo);
        label1.setBounds(0, 0, 800, 600);
        add(label1);

        label1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){  
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)  
            {
                int x= e.getX();
                int y=e.getY();
                System.out.println();
                if(x>120 && x<150 && y>80 && y<110){
                    drawCircle(667,280);
                }
                if(x>174 && x<214 && y>125 && y<170){
                    drawCircle(667,280);
                }
                if(x>250 && x<270 && y>150 && y<240){
                    drawCircle(667,320);
                }
                if(x>375 && x<402 && y>75 && y<112){
                    drawCircle(670,359);
                }
                if(x>440 && x<490 && y>180 && y<215){
                    drawCircle(675,397);
                }
                if(x>535 && x<615 && y>110 && y<140){
                    drawCircle(670,437);
                }
                removeMouseListener(this);
            }  
        });

        setSize(800,600);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    }

    public void drawCircle(int x, int y) {
        Graphics g = getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawOval(x,y,70,30);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        EagleEye e= new EagleEye();
    }
}
```